# ajax easyutocomplete only returns first 6 values

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, easyautocomplete

I'm trying to follow this example: http://easyautocomplete.com/example/ajax-get to create an input field that will autocomplete hints from API.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>

  <head>
    <!-- Easy Autocomplete -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete.themes.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Easy Autocomplete -->
    <script src="/plugins/easy-autocomplete/dist/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var options = {
        url: "http://localhost:8081/api/customers",

        getValue: "name",

        template: {
          type: "description",
          fields: {
            description: "email"
          }
        }
      };

      $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready");
        $("#example-ajax-post").easyAutocomplete(options);
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="example-ajax-post" />
  </body>

</html>
```

In my API response, I can see all my returned values (26 in total) however my input displaying only first 6 hints, even if I try to enter some data that's in my response I can only see the first 6 loaded fields each time.

[API Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vLN5.png)

[Input hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzzYD.png)

Am I missing something?

Comment: did my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: work like a charm, thanks @JoeWarner

Comment: your welcome have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Default value for parameter maxNumberOfElements is 6.

you can increase this by adding this to your options

```
 list: {
   maxNumberOfElements: 10,
     match: {
        enabled: true
    }
 }
```

> Docs
>    http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-maxsize